# What does Node.js 'require()' return if there is nothing assigned to module.exports

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to require() a file in Node.js which has valid JavaScript code in it but no assignments to 'exports' or 'module.exports'. It seems to me the result of require() is in such a case sometimes undefined, but sometimes it is an empty Object({}).

What should require() return if there is no exports-assignments in the file being required? Thanks

Comment: Please post an example code where you get `undefined` and where you get `Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does Node.js 'require()' return if there is nothing assigned to module.exports

`module.exports` is by default an empty object (an object with no custom properties).  So, that's what a `require()` would return if the module itself doesn't assign any properties to the object.

The only way `require()` could return `undefined` is if there's a problem loading the module (though usually that will throw an exception) or the module itself assigns `undefined` to `module.exports`.  To help you further with your particular situation that you say returns `undefined`, then you will have share with us a reproducible case that does that.

Comment: I have some trouble limiting the code-set that seems to cause this.  So I'm happy to know it SHOULD NOT happen. So assumably there is some error which gets hidden by some error-handler perhaps. That's 
 a good clue. Thanks.